# How to calculate the generators for the multiplicative group $\Bbb Z_4^*$

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

I read online that the generator for the cyclic group $(\Bbb Z_4^*,\times)$, where $\Bbb Z_4^*:=\{1,2,3,4\}$ are 2 and 3 .

I tried working this out but it doesn't make sense to me , here's what I did ;

$$\langle2\rangle=\{2^0,2^1,2^2,...\}=\{1,2,0\}$$, But three is not included in this set ?

$$\langle3\rangle:=\{3^0,3^1,3^2,3^3,...\}=\{1,3\}$$.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Nop. The elements of the multiplicative group of units modulo $\;4\;$ are $\;\Bbb Z_4^*=\{1,3\}\;$ , and its unique generator is $\;3\;$ . Nevertheless, by what you wrote, it seems to be you mean some other group...but I can't figure out which one.

Comment: oh, do you have any links to material on the multiplicative group mod 4 because I don't understand why this is so ?

Comment: I assumed it was like the generators of $\Bbb Z$ under addition which would be $\langle1\rangle$ and $\langle2,3,\rangle$ which we just get by adding them all up

Comment: Usually, one takes the elements of $\mathbb{Z}/n$ which are relatively prime to $n$ for the multiplicative group.  Therefore, $(\mathbb{Z}/4)^\ast=\{1,3\}$.  You can't just change the operation, the set changes too.

Comment: @MichaelBurr this is in contrast to the additve groups then correct ? which has $\Bbb Z_4:=\{1,2,3,4\}$

Comment: @MichaelBurr I've studied some additive groups but not really much multiplicative groups

Comment: Yes, the additive group is $\mathbb{Z}/4=\{0,1,2,3\}$.

Comment: The notation $R^\ast$ when $R$ is a ring (i.e., has both additive and multiplicative structures) means that you take the units in the ring.  You'll find plenty of resources on the web if you search for some of these words.

Comment: @MichaelBurr oh thank god, for a moment there when DonAntonio gave his comment I thought maybe it was the same for additive groups and I just had a group theory exam where one had to find the generators for an additive group and I worried I'd answred it completely incorrectly ....phew XD

Comment: @MichaelBurr Thank you for your comments by the way, I understand now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ring of integers modulo $\;4\;$ is the set of equivalence classes of residues modulo $\;4\;$ in the integers $\;\Bbb Z\;$, meaning: all the possible residues one can obtain when dividing any integer by four.

The set of representatives for the four equivalence classes is usually taken to be $\;\{0,1,2,3\}\;\pmod 4\;$, yet this does **not** have to be this way. For example, the set you took $\;\{1,2,3,4\}\;$ is also a full set of representatives of residues modulo $\;4\;$ .

So we can take $\;\Bbb Z_4=\{0,1,2,3\}=\{1,2,3,4\}=\{-3,-1,2,12\}\;$ , etc. Any set with four integers which are **different** residues modulo $\;4\;$ can do it, so by simplicity we assume $\;\Bbb Z_4=\{0,1,3,4\}\pmod4\;$

Now, for any (commutative, for simplicity) unitaru ring $\;R\;$ , the set $\;R^*\;$ is the set of all units in the ring, meaning:

$$R^*:=\{r\in R\;|\;\exists\,s\in R\;\;s.t.\;\;rs=1\}$$

In your case, $\;\Bbb Z_4^*=\{1,3\}\;$ , as you can easily check. As this is an abelian (multiplcative) group of prime order, it is cyclic...and etc.

Comment: Ah thank you this all makes a lot more sense now :) I do have one small question though . I was under the impression ( which seems somewhat misguided now ) that the number of primitive elements in $\Bbb F_5$ is given by the number of generators in its multiplicative cyclic group $F_4^*$. I thought that one calculated the number of such elements using the Euler totient formula $\phi(4)=4(1-\frac{1}{2})=2$ which would give 2 primitive elements and hence two generators . Am i completely wrong in this ? Or is there some truth and I'm just applying it wrong ?

Comment: I was under that impression because of this site http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Max.Neunhoeffer/Teaching/ff2013/ff2013.pdf definition 6.10 and example 6.11. pg 25 and 26. Is this website an untrustworthy sousre ? or is it my mistake ?

Comment: @exodius Maybe you are, or maybe you're simply mixing things: in *this matter*, you do not mix residues! One thing is $\;\Bbb Z_5\;$ , modulo five, and way another is $\;\Bbb Z_4\;$ . Now, it is true that $\;\Bbb Z_5^*\cong\Bbb Z_4\;$ , as both groups are cyclic of the same order 4 (yet observe the left one is multiplicative, whereas the right one is additive...!), and the number of generators in a cyclic group of order $\;n\;$ indeed is $\;\varphi(n)\;,\;\;\varphi=$ Euler's Totient Function, but if you mix the two above then it can be a mess

Comment: Thus, in the form of $\;\Bbb Z_5^*\;$ , the generators are $\;\{2,3\}\pmod 5\;$ , whereas in the form $\;\Bbb Z_4\;$ the generators are $\;\{1,3\}\pmod4\;$ ...see how this can easily get messy? As an intellectual exercise it can be nice to prove $\;\Bbb Z_5^*\cong\Bbb Z_4\;$ , yet as a way to try to understand things when beginning this beautiful subject it can be rather annoying and confusing...

Comment: ...and observe how in that paper you linked, they don't switch between modulo $\;4\;$ and modulo $\;5\;$ or something else. That's fine later, when these things sink in and well understood.

Comment: I think I understand now the cyclic group $\Bbb F_5^*:=\{1,2,3,4\}$ as all of these have gcd=1 with 5. then$ 2=2,2^2=4,2^3=3,2^4=1$ $3^2=4,3^3=2,3^4=1,3=3$ so both are generators for the group ? If this is correct I'm gonna just stick to this way because that swapping between $\Bbb Z_5^*$ and $\Bbb Z_4$ is very confusing to me

Comment: Yes, that is right. I'd say that one usually gets to do exercises like this one **after** one studies a little about cyclic groups, their generators and etc.